# Chosen.js with input field of type text which styled as select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to apply chosen.js to an input field. Here is my code

```
<label>
   <input type="text"/>
   <div class="custom-placeholder">
      <span>Placeholder text</span>
   </div>
   <div><img src="dropdown icon.img"/></div>
</label>
```

The above code output exactly appears a select box (I styled throught my project). Now ,I want to use it as chosen.js select box. Please help me. If I use  instead of above code, I need to change a lot of styles

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/Da4m3/

**Update**

Please attach below links on your page:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js

```
    <select id="first" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
              <option value=""></option> 
              <option value="United States">United States</option> 
              <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
              <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option> 
              <option value="Albania">Albania</option> 
              <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
              <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option> 
              <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option> 
              <option value="Angola">Angola</option> 
              <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option> 
            </select>
<script>
$(function()
{
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
})
</script>
```

if you want to select only one item at a time then remove attribute **multiple** .

Comment: please keep fiddle link and copy paste the fiddle code in the answer. I have some fiddle problem